# Python TypeError when using zip* to unpackoutputs

Tags: python, parallel-processing, zip, typeerror

I am running a function, which returns multiple outputs, in Python in parallel. I would like to use zip*(output) in order to unpack the outputs. My code is as follows

```
x1, x2, x3, x4 = zip*(Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(sim)(pred = dat, trt_unit = i, extra = 1, test = 2) for i in (dat.fips.unique())))
```

However, doing so yields:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'type'

If I run the command without zip* and assign it to one output variable x, it returns a list with one element which is a tuple of 4 that countains x1, x2, x3, x4 as expected.

```
x = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(sim)(pred = dat, trt_unit = i, extra = 1, test = 2) for i in (dat.fips.unique()))
```

Output:
[image]

However, I cannot get the zip* to work.

Comment: try moving the `*` inside the open paren after `zip`: `zip(*Parallel...)`

Comment: Thank you @AbbeGijly that worked!